# Connection is made to the database with php script but no values are returned

Tags: php, mysql

I have a successful connection to the database through this php script but it is not returning any values even though it is connected. I am checking for the results on my web browser and it just returns a blank screen. I have used the same script (different queries) to access two other tables in the database and they are both working fine. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$username = "xx"; 
$password = "xxx";   
$host = "xxxxx";
$database="xxxxx";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

$myquery = "SELECT `AUTHOR`, `In_order` from `authors`";

$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);


?>
```

It is probably some silly mistake that I have over looked but I have been stuck on it for longer than I should! thanks in advance for any feedback

Comment: You're completely sure that the "authors" table isn't empty? Does it have any other columns other than `AUTHOR` and `In_order`? Try selecting those instead and let us know what happens.

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php (including the first warning) and compare your call of mysql_fetch_assoc with the one in the example.

Comment: And if you suspect you get no data, maybe you should echo the result of `mysql_num_rows()` to be sure that this is the case.

Comment: Yes the authors table is fully populated, and there is another column ID and I selected that and no change and no error just a blank result

Answer (score 0):

Tried you code locally on some data and it returns everything ok.
I needed to change the select to match my data

So I am 95% sure the problem is in your query / db settings.

I would first check if your columns in database is really called `AUTHOR` and 'In_order' with the exact capital letters.

MySql names can be case sensitive depending on your db server settings, and this could be the problem

*Sidenote*: if you can research mysqli and pdo for connecting to DB instead of mysql that is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have got the right column names exactly so unfortunately problem is still not solved, even more puzzling now that its definitely confirmed that it is successfully connecting!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$myquery = "SELECT `AUTHOR`, `In_order` from `authors`";
$query = mysql_query($myquery);
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
var_dump($query);
var_dump($num);
echo mysql_error();
```

and tell us what it all says.

**Edit**: okay, so it's 231 rows in your table, as the `var_dump($num)` says. Now let's try and get them at last, but in a slightly more efficient way:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

I have a feeling that your "for" loop and `mysql_fetch_assoc()` inside is what plays tricks with you, because both of them use different internal counters.

Comment: `resource(4) of type (mysql result) int(231)` this is what it returned